# Html2canvas - Using one button to create screen shots of two different pages

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, pdf, html2canvas

I have a button, Printer Friendly, which creates a screenshot of a table within the Route Check In tab.  I have another tab, LCP, where I would like the same button to capture a screen shot of this page when I go the LCP tab.

Here is the code within rollup.js where the html2canvas is created when you click the Printer Friendly button.

```
app.controller('Rollup', function($scope, $rootScope, $http, $uibModal, headersvc, locFiltersvc) {
.....
$scope.printDiv = function(divName) {

html2canvas(document.getElementById("routeContent"), {

        onrendered: function (canvas) {

            var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            var doc = new jsPDF();

            doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG',1,30,210,230);

            //HEADER TEST
            doc.text(5, 5, "Header");

            doc.save('Route.pdf');

        //OPEN IN NEW WINDOW TEST
            //doc.output('dataurlnewwindow');

            //IE 9-11 WORK AROUND
            if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE ") > 0 || 
                    navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./)) 
            {
                var blob = canvas.msToBlob();
                window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob,'Test file.png');
            }


        },
    }); 

//html2canvas for LCP tab
    /*
    html2canvas(document.getElementById("divPrint"), {

        onrendered: function (canvas) {

            //document.body.appendChild(canvas);

            var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            var doc = new jsPDF();
            //alters size of the pdf preview
                //doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG',1,1,205,100);

            doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG',1,1,210,110);

            doc.save('LCP.pdf');

            //IE 9-11 WORK AROUND
            if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE ") > 0 || 
                    navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./)) 
            {
                var blob = canvas.msToBlob();
                window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob,'Test file.png');
            }

        },
    }); 
    */

}

});
```

How can I combine both to work when I click the button within the specific tab?  Thanks.

I also want the screen shot to open in a new tab rather than the screenshot saving as a pdf.
Any help is appreciated.